# Out of memory error in my program

Tags: java, arraylist, java-8, out-of-memory

I had written a program that does some data processing on a list (max 800 in size) of objects. The work done on this list was mainly the following:

1. A lot of SQL queries
2. Processing the queried data
3. Grouping and Matching
4. Writing them to CSV files

All this was working totally fine, however the data processing part and the size of SQL data increased day by day and the program started running out of memory and crashed often.

To avoid this I decided to chop this big list into a few smaller chunks and then try to do the same work on these smaller lists (I would clear and nullifying the current small list before going to the next small list) hoping that it would solve the problem. But this has not helped at all and the program still runs out of memory.

The program does not run out of memory in the first iteration of the for loop But in the second or the third or so.

Am I correctly clearing and nullifying all the lists and objects in the for loop so that memory gets free for the next iteration?

How do I solve this problem? I have put my code below.

Any suggestions/solutions will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.
Cheers !

```
List<someObject> unchoppedList = new ArrayList<someObject>();
for (String pb : listOfNames) {
    someObject tccw = null;
    tccw = new someObject(...);
    unchoppedList.add(tccw);
}
Collections.shuffle(unchoppedList);
List<List<someObject>> master = null;
if (unchoppedList.size() > 0 && unchoppedList.size() <= 175) {
    master = chopped(unchoppedList, 1);
} else if (unchoppedList.size() > 175 && unchoppedList.size() <= 355) {
    master = chopped(unchoppedList, 2);
} else if (unchoppedList.size() > 355 && unchoppedList.size() <= 535) {
    master = chopped(unchoppedList, 3);
} else if (unchoppedList.size() > 535&& unchoppedList.size() <= 800)) {
    master = chopped(unchoppedList, 4);
}

for (int i = 0 ; i < master.size() ; i++) {
    List<someObject> m = master.get(i);
    System.gc(); // I insterted this statement to force GC
    executor1 = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(Configuration.getNumberOfProcessors());
    generalList = new ArrayList<ProductBean>();
    try {
        m.parallelStream().forEach(work -> {
            try {
                generalList.addAll(executor1.submit(work).get());
                work = null;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                logError(e);
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logError(e);
    }
    executor1.shutdown();
    executor1.awaitTermination(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    m.clear();
    m = null;
    executor1 = null;

    //once the general list is produced the program randomly matches some "good" products to highly similar "not-so-good" products
    List<ProductBean> controlList = new ArrayList<ProductBean>();
    List<ProductBean> tempKaseList = new ArrayList<ProductBean>();
    for (ProductBean kase : generalList) {
        if (kase.getGoodStatus() == 0 && kase.getBadStatus() == 1) {
            controlList.add(kase1);
        } else if (kase.getGoodStatus() == 1 && kase.getBadStatus() == 0) {
            tempKaseList.add(kase1);
        }
    }
    generalList = new ArrayList<ProductBean>(tempKaseList);
    tempKaseList.clear();
    tempKaseList = null;

    Collections.shuffle(generalList);
    Collections.shuffle(controlList);
    final List<List<ProductBean>> compliCases = chopped(generalList, 3);
    final List<List<ProductBean>> compliControls = chopped(controlList, 3);
    generalList.clear();
    controlList.clear();
    generalList = null;
    controlList = null;

    final List<ProductBean> remainingCases = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<ProductBean>());
    IntStream.range(0, compliCases.size()).parallel().forEach(i -> {
        compliCases.get(i).forEach(c -> {
            TheRandomMatchWorker tRMW = new TheRandomMatchWorker(compliControls.get(i), c);
            List<String[]> reportData = tRMW.generateReport();
            writeToCSVFile(reportData);
            // if the program cannot find required number of products to match it is added to a new list to look for matching candidates elsewhere
            if (tRMW.getTheKase().isEverythingMathced == false) {
                remainingCases.add(tRMW.getTheKase());
            }
            compliControls.get(i).removeAll(tRMW.getTheMatchedControls());
            tRMW = null;
            stuff.clear();
        });
    });

    controlList = new ArrayList<ProductBean>();
    for (List<ProductBean> c10 : compliControls) {
        controlList.addAll(c10);
    }
    compliCases.clear();
    compliControls.clear();

    //last sweep where the program for last time tries to match some "good" products to highly similar "not-so-good" products
    try {
        for (ProductBean kase : remainingCases) {
            if (kase.getNoOfContrls() < ccv.getNoofctrl()) {
                TheRandomMatchWorker tRMW = new TheRandomMatchWorker(controlList, kase );
                List<String[]> reportData = tRMW.generateReport();
                writeToCSVFile(reportData);
                if (tRMW.getTheKase().isEverythingMathced == false) {
                    remainingCases.add(tRMW.getTheKase());
                }
                compliControls.get(i).removeAll(tRMW.getTheMatchedControls());
                tRMW = null;
                stuff.clear();
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logError(e);
    }

    remainingCases.clear();
    controlList.clear();
    controlList = null;
    master.get(i).clear();
    master.set(i, null);
    System.gc();
}
master.clear();
master = null;
```

Here is the chopped method

```
static <T> List<List<T>> chopped(List<T> list, final int L) {
    List<List<T>> parts = new ArrayList<List<T>>();
    final int N = list.size();
    int y = N / L, m = 0, c = y;
    int r = c * L;
    for (int i = 1; i <= L; i++) {
        if (i == L) {
            c += (N - r);
        }
        parts.add(new ArrayList<T>(list.subList(m, c)));
        m = c;
        c += y;
    }
    return parts;
}
```

Here is the stack trace as requested

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
    at Controller.MasterStudyController.lambda$1(MasterStudyController.java:212)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:184)
    at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1374)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachTask.compute(ForEachOps.java:291)
    at java.util.concurrent.CountedCompleter.exec(CountedCompleter.java:731)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.execLocalTasks(ForkJoinPool.java:1040)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1058)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
    at org.postgresql.core.Encoding.decode(Encoding.java:204)
    at org.postgresql.core.Encoding.decode(Encoding.java:215)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgResultSet.getString(PgResultSet.java:1913)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgResultSet.getString(PgResultSet.java:2484)
    at Controller.someObject.findControls(someObject.java:214)
    at Controller.someObject.call(someObject.java:81)
    at Controller.someObject.call(someObject.java:1)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[19:13:35][ERROR] Jarvis: Exception:
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.AssertionError: Failed generating bytecode for <eval>:-1
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
    at Controller.MasterStudyController.lambda$1(MasterStudyController.java:212)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:184)
    at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1374)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachTask.compute(ForEachOps.java:291)
    at java.util.concurrent.CountedCompleter.exec(CountedCompleter.java:731)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.execLocalTasks(ForkJoinPool.java:1040)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1058)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)
Caused by: java.lang.AssertionError: Failed generating bytecode for <eval>:-1
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.codegen.CompilationPhase$BytecodeGenerationPhase.transform(CompilationPhase.java:431)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.codegen.CompilationPhase.apply(CompilationPhase.java:624)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.codegen.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:655)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.Context.compile(Context.java:1317)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.Context.compileScript(Context.java:1251)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.Context.compileScript(Context.java:627)
    at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.compileImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java:535)
    at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.compileImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java:524)
    at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.evalImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java:402)
    at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.eval(NashornScriptEngine.java:155)
    at javax.script.AbstractScriptEngine.eval(AbstractScriptEngine.java:264)
    at Controller.someObject.findCases(someObject.java:108)
    at Controller.someObject.call(someObject.java:72)
    at Controller.someObject.call(someObject.java:1)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
[19:13:52][ERROR] Jarvis: Exception:
[19:51:41][ERROR] Jarvis: Exception:
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Ran out of memory retrieving query results.
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2157)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:300)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:428)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:354)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:169)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeQuery(PgPreparedStatement.java:117)
    at Controller.someObject.lookForSomething(someObject.java:763)
    at Controller.someObject.call(someObject.java:70)
    at Controller.someObject.call(someObject.java:1)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
```

Comment: Can you provide the stacktrace?

Comment: How much memory have you given the JVM? Have you tried looking at memory usage with VisualVM?

Comment: 48GB is the size I assign before starting this program. Yes I have used VisualVM but I failed to recognize anything from it.

Comment: The stacktraces that you have given do not seem to occur in the code above so I don't think they help much. The given code is also a bit too big, while still being incomplete. You should reduce it to a [mcve] that shows that the OOME can be reproduced by running just this piece of code. Finally, there appears to be several multi-threading issues like adding to an unsynchronized `ArrayList` in parallel.

Comment: Didier L - adding to unsynchronized ArrayList is not a problem there I think. Yes stack traces do not go in sync with the code because OOME occurs some where in the middle of the loop. In some other Run it occurs else where, it does not happen at the same position every time. The big problem here is memory is not getting free'd though I am clearing all the lists and nullifying them

Comment: What's your SQL query? Out of memory is caused by the postgreSQL driver. "org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Ran out of memory retrieving query results."

Comment: All SQL queries in my program are SELECT statements with some simple WHERE clause

Comment: Is that you put everything from your resultset to your `unchoppedList` for processing?

Comment: Alex -  No unchoppedList is just a list of strings. All the data from ResultSet goes to someObject as String LocalDate and int.

Comment: @krisGoks Why do you think that violating ArrayList's requirements is OK? It is not thread-safe so you should take care of it.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, 48GB of memory for the JVM is quite a lot (I assume you are talking about heap space, so `-Xmx48G`). We are clearly talking about big datasets here, which of course complicates things as it's not easy to create minimal reproducible examples.

The first thing I would try is to get more insight into what is consuming all memory. You can get Java to produce a heap dump when it runs out of memory using the following options:

```
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/tmp
```

This should create a java_xxxxxx.hprof file in /tmp when your program crashes due to an OutOfMemoryError.

You can then attempt to use tools to analyze this dump, though the huge size will present challenges. Trying to simply open it in [MAT](https://www.eclipse.org/mat/) for example will very likely not work, but there are ways to run parts of it on the commandline - possibly remotely on a beefy server.

There are some articles describing analysis of large heap dumps:

- [A blog post on analyzing large dumps with MAT](https://javaforu.blogspot.be/2013/11/analyzing-large-java-heap-dumps-when.html)
- [An article on analyzing an 18GB heap dump using MAT](http://www.techpaste.com/2015/07/how-to-analyse-large-heap-dumps/)

In short, these instructions boil down to:

- Download and install MAT
- Configure memory settings for MAT according to what you have available during analysis (obviously, more = better)
- It should include a `ParseHeapDump.sh` script which you can use to run some analysis and prepare index/report files. Note that this can of course take a very long time.

  ```
  ./ParseHeapDump.sh /path/to/your.hprof
  ./ParseHeapDump.sh /path/to/your.hprof org.eclipse.mat.api:suspects
  ./ParseHeapDump.sh /path/to/your.hprof org.eclipse.mat.api:overview
  ./ParseHeapDump.sh /path/to/your.hprof org.eclipse.mat.api:top_components
  ```

You should then be able to open the generated reports with MAT an hopefully make something useful of them.

---

In your comment, you say most memory is being used by lists of SomeObjects and suspect these are not being freed.

Based on the code you posted, the SomeObject objects are not being freed because they are still accessible through the `unchoppedList` list: that list is not cleared in the code you post, so the calls to `m.clear()` have virtually no effect on used memory as all those objects are still referenced elsewhere.

So, the solution might be as simple as adding a line `unchoppedList.clear();` after populating your master list:

```
List<List<someObject>> master = null;
// lets also get rid of hardcoded numbers of lists
int maxListSize = 175;
int nbSublists = (unchoppedList.size() + maxListSize - 1) / maxListSize; // obtain rounded up integer division
master = chopped(unchoppedList, nbSublists);
// important: clear the unchoppedList so it doesn't keep references to *all* SomeObject
unchoppedList.clear();
```

---

In response to other comments about non-threadsafe uses of ArrayList, I must agree with others that this is generally a bad idea.

To address the most obvious one, I don't even see a good reason to use `parallelStream` when submitting work to your executor. Using a normal sequential stream would ensure this is again thread-safe (thus eliminating a potential source of problems).

Note that if there even is a performance impact from this change I believe it may even be positive.

- The lambda expression is trivial and will thus execute very fast; the theoretical maximum benefit from a parallel stream seems minimal
- Each sequential item that gets processed starts a new thread until the executor is at its maximum, so all cores should be busy almost instantaneously
- Using a parallel stream creates a lot of overhead even by itself, and in this case the parallel stream threads will additionally have to compete with the executor threads for CPU time

Aside from that there may still be other concurrency issues at play; without the full program it's difficult to evaluate but your `writeToCSVFile(reportData);` call for example looks potentially problematic as well.

Comment: Yes the datasets I am dealing with are really huge in size (~800 Gigs). I tried running VisualVm and monitor the process while the program runs. I can see what is consuming the memory. It is largely the 10000s of someObjects in ArrayLists. But the problem is when it goes to the second or third iteration, the objects from first iteration are not getting released(this is what I think is happening), but I do not know how to confirm it. Hence I have started the quest of finding out how to free memory from those old iteration objects and see if it helps.

Comment: I found a suspected cause for your issue and updated my answer with a surprisingly simple solution if that is indeed the problem. In addition I also added a short section on thread-safety/concurrency.

Comment: Yes, I suspected the same, as far as I know objects are alive where it should not be, I am trying out what you have suggested and will let you know once I do